# Css: Glow effect that takes background color into account?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create more or less realistic looking leds with HTML and CSS. Adding a a glow to every led would be pretty straight forward if the color of the led was static. But I actually want the glow to automatically adjust to the led color. 
So this wouldn't work: https://fiddle.jshell.net/dwv5xxws/
And please don't tell me to create a class for every color. In the end I want the leds to fade between colors, so I would have to create millions of classes.

```css
.led {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px #ff0000;
  
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="led" style="background-color:red"></div>
<div class="led" style="background-color:green"></div>
<div class="led" style="background-color:blue"></div>
```

**This is what inspired me btw:**
http://codepen.io/fskirschbaum/pen/MYJNaj

edit:
Just an idea.. maybe we can just increase the size of the leds and make a shadow overlay inside of those leds so that it appears like the outer circle is just the "glow" and not the led itself.

Comment: Why not just make a different CSS class for each LED?

Comment: is given codepen example ok? https://fiddle.jshell.net/dwv5xxws/2/

Comment: @Zac Because I'm planning to make the leds fade through every possible color from #000000 to #ffffff.  And I don't feel like creating 16777216 classes right now.

Comment: @FastSnail Well, no. When the background color of the led is changed, I want the glow to automatically look correct.

Comment: Oh, okay - I think I have an idea and I'll probably post an answer in a few minutes

Comment: @Forivin you could use javascript

Comment: @FastSnail I'm planning to work with a few hundret leds in the end and the background-color changes happen like every 10 milliseconds. It is already very very CPU hungry, I think more js would make the whole thing start lagging.

Comment: @Forivin canvas is more suitable

Comment: @FastSnail Indeed, but I noticed it too late in development and going back that far would be too time consuming unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS Variables are still at a very early stage, but one well-established, reliable variable in CSS is `currentColor` - which, as its name suggests, always takes the current value of whatever `color:` is.

So a slight tweak to your code above will give you exactly what you want:

```css
.led {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px currentColor;
  
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="led" style="color:red"></div>
<div class="led" style="color:green"></div>
<div class="led" style="color:blue"></div>
```

For browser support of `currentColor`, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=currentcolor

Comment: Very nice ! - Didn't know that it could be used with inline styles :-)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! Does a variable for this also exist for background-color per se?

Comment: It doesn't. And furthermore, I've just realised, the forthcoming _CSS Variables_ module doesn't look like it could produce something equivalent to a `backgroundColor` variable either... as it looks like each variable can only access a static value, not a named property (which has a currentValue).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I used JS to iterate all the elements with the class 'led', then set their box shadows to their background colours:

```
leds = document.getElementsByClassName('led');
for (var l = 0; l < leds.length; l++) {
    led = leds[l];
    led.style.boxShadow = '0 0 10px 1px ' + led.style.backgroundColor;
}
```

If you change the background colour of an element, make sure to run this code again.

Answer (score 1):

It is your idea, after all ...

```css
.led {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 11px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="led" style="background-color:red"></div>
<div class="led" style="background-color:green"></div>
<div class="led" style="background-color:blue"></div>
```